# Adding new row to an existing data frame with a function

Tags: r, function, assign

I want to add a new row to an existing data frame, using a function like this:

```
df <- data.frame(num1 = numeric(),
                 num2 = numeric(),
                 int1 = integer(),
                 chr1 = character(),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

filler <- function () {
  newrow = c(0.1, 0.01, 100, "char")
  df[nrow(df)+1, ] <- newrow
  assign(x = "df", value = df, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
filler
```

but nothing is happening.

I'd like to get the following output:

```
> df
  num1 num2 int1 chr1
1  0.1 0.01  100 char
```

Note: I don't want to define the new table within a function, because I want to rerun the function afterwards with different "newrow" values.

Comment: This line will coerce all values to `character` BTW: `c(0.1, 0.01, 100, "char")`.

Comment: You should pass `df` into the function and `return` the modified data frame to have the function fit into the functional programming paradigm. Or have the function not touch the data frame and just return a 1-line data frame of the row to add. In either case, just use `rbind()` inside the function or out of it.

Comment: @Gregor - your solution worked fine. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick for you. I used a generic a row so you can pass new values to the data frame. You can pass a vector of values by doing the following: c(value1, value2, value3, value4)

```
df <- data.frame(num1 = numeric(),
                 num2 = numeric(),
                 int1 = integer(),
                 chr1 = character(),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

row_attempt <- c(1,2,3,"Master")

filler <- function(frame_to_attach, my_row){
    newrow = my_row
    data_frame <- rbind(frame_to_attach,my_row)
    colnames(data_frame) <- colnames(frame_to_attach)
   return(data_frame)
}

z <- filler(df, row_attempt)
z
```

Comment: @sandoronodi You are just not assigning the result; this answer works just fine. `df <- filler(df, row_attempt)` now I have one row, `df <- filler(df, row_attempt)` now two, run it as many times as you like, just assign use `df <- ` to assign the output each time.